# Using the first fundamental theorem of calculus to derive Taylor expansion/series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, taylor-expansion

Appendix C of my textbook, *Algorithms for Optimization*, by Kochenderfer and Wheeler, begins to derive the **Taylor expansion/series** as follows:

> From the *first fundamental theorem of calculus*, we know that
>
> $$f(x + h) = f(x) + \int_0^h f'(x + a) \ da$$

Something about this application of the first fundamental theorem seemed wrong to me, so I looked at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Proof_of_the_first_part). The article presents the relevant equation as

$$F(x_{1}+\Delta x)-F(x_{1})=\int _{x_{1}}^{x_{1}+\Delta x}f(t)\,dt.\qquad$$

If we set $\Delta x = h$, $t = x + a$, and $x_1 = 0$, we get

$$F(0 + h)-F(0)=\int _{0}^{0+h}f(x + a)\,dt,\qquad$$

which is a different result from what the author has.

I'm confused as to how the author's result is valid. I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a fixed $x$, let $g(h)=f(x+h)$. Then $g'(h)=f'(x+h)$ and\begin{align}f(x+h)-f(x)&=g(h)-g(0)\\&=\int_0^hg'(a)\,\mathrm da\text{ (by the fundamental theorem of Calculus)}\\&=\int_0^hf'(x+a)\,\mathrm da.\end{align}So, yes, that textbook of yours is correct.

Note that your equality$$F(0+h)-F(0)=\int _0^{0+h}f(x+a)\,dt,$$is weird, since the RHS depends on $x$, whereas the LHS doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Set not $x_1=0$, but $x_1=x$.  Also, what Wikipedia calls $F$ would in your example be $f$.  Then Wikipedia's $f$ would become $f'$, and we would have:$$f(x + h)-f(x)=\int _{x}^{x+h}f'(t)\,dt,\qquad$$
From there, a substitution $t=x+a, dt=da$ would give the author's claim.